# Check status of triggered Azure Function

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to create e2e test for application I am working on. It consists of web application that stores some files in Blob Storage and Azure function that process those files once a day.

I wanted to write test in nodejs that would execute certain actions on website (using WDIO), then trigger function by HTTP request (as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http) and after, if function finished successfully, check if it created files in appropriate locations.

Although the problem with this, is that after sending request to trigger the function, it doesn't return any handle/jobId and I am not able to check its status. Is there any way that i could do this?

If I had runId i could probably query Application Insights to see if a job finished/failed.

**As for now i do this:**

I query Application Insights for logs that were created after test started (It's not ideal solution although in my case there shouldn't be any more instances running at the same time). If there are no logs at the moment, i retry every minute up to 5 times. After this I parse them looking for message if job succeded.

Query i use:

```
union traces
| union exceptions
| union requests
| where cloud_RoleName =~ '${APP_NAME}' and operation_Name =~ '${OPERATION_NAME}' | order by timestamp desc
| where message contains 'Processing' or message contains 'Executed' or message contains 'Archived' or innermostMessage contains 'Exception'
| where timestamp > make_datetime("${DATE.toISOString()}")
| project message, innermostMessage
```

Although this have one big downfall, because it can take up to even 5 minutes (usually around 3) for logs too appear in Application Insights :/.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get the instance id of azure function:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ExecutionContext ec,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string iid = ec.InvocationId.ToString();
            return new OkObjectResult(iid);
        }
    }
}
```

And use this to get the status of instance of azure function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/get-instance-info

Also, you can use application insight to get the status(as you mentioned in your question), this is easier.

Comment: Sadly i have TimerTrigger function so i can't return anything :|